# remove title bar ,menu bar ,navigation bar ,tab bar ,address bar and statusbar of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I remove the title bar, menu bar, navigation bar, tab bar, address bar , status bar of the browser using jquery.

The thing is that I am calling a dialog to open a poup window which should fit the monitor screen fully and should not show any bars of the browser.

Comment: why do you need jquery for that?just go in settings and change it.

Comment: "Title bar" as in the thing that contains the close button? Like... seriously? Please no.

Comment: New browsers have a fullscreen API, you can use that.

Comment: It's always a bad idea to try to control the browser window. Users (and security folks) will hate you. But have a look at the fullscreen API as @elclanrs said

Comment: People always seem to downvote questions against their views or thoughts, just because it's a silly idea doesn't make it a bad question. Upvoted.

Comment: People should realize that sometimes we are developing to an enterprise environment and in that case we are forced to do something that goes against the "user freedom".

Answer (score 8):

The [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_full-screen_mode) provides an easy way for web content to be presented using the user's entire screen. This article provides information about using this API.

The API lets you easily direct the browser to make an element and its children, if any, occupy the fullscreen, eliminating all browser user interface and other applications from the screen for the duration.

[Live Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/fullscreen.html) (Press Enter after site loads)

[This](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/02/enhance-your-website-fullscreen-api/) is also a good read.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to be able to hide all of those toolbars, but you can do your best by setting the false value for whatever options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open ...in the third parameter for `window.open`, most likely these:

- menubar
- toolbar
- location
- scrollbars
- titlebar

(not all fully compatible/supported, but it can't hurt to use them)

As for being "full screen" - the next best thing to the fullscreen API is to use these options for the third parameter of `window.open`:

```
window.open("url", "name", "top=0,left=0,width=" + window.screen.width + ",height=" + window.screen.height);
```

But that doesn't even guarantee it will fill the full monitor.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open("url","name",'height=240,width=200,top=' + top + ',left=' + left + ',directories=no,titlebar=nostatus=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,navigationbar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
```